# Using a conditional length in ANT

Tags: ant, conditional-statements

I am currently trying to use the length task in ANT, more specifically making a conditional length task.

I want to to flag a message to a currently existing file if a file is greater than a set length, like so:

```
<project name="ant" default="check-filesize">
<target name="check-filesize">
    <length mode="all" property="fs.length.bytes" when="gt" length="100">
    <fileset dir="size" includes="*"/>
    </length>
    <echo>sorry your file set is to large</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

I have already written the code to print the size of all files in the directory but I haven't included it here to keep this brief.

If length does not allow for the echo tag can I perform this another way if not does any one know what the when tag does ?  Obviously I only want the echo to happen when the condition is violated

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a way to do this using no external libraries, but thankyou for your help. here is how :

```
<project name="ant" default="check-filesize">
<target name="check-filesize">
  <fail message="Your File Exceeds Limitations Please Operator For Full Size Of Data Set>
    <condition>
      <length length="1000" when="gt" mode="all" property="fs.length.bytes">
         <fileset dir="size" includes="*"/>
      </length>
    </condition>
   </fail>
 </target>
 </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to conditionally echo a statement using Ant's built-in tasks:

```
<project name="ant-length" default="check-filesize">
    <target name="check-filesize" depends="get-length, echo-if-large"/>

    <target name="get-length">
        <condition property="fs.length.too.large">
            <length mode="all" when="gt" length="100">
                <fileset dir="size" includes="*"/>
            </length>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="echo-if-large" if="fs.length.too.large">
        <echo>sorry your file set is too large</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

The third-party [Ant-Contrib library](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) has an [`<if>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) that simplifies this.